# flutter location package have error in build project

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i add the location package to my pubspec.yamel of project and when i build my project i get this error:

> > FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task
> ':app:processDebugResources'. A failure occurred while executing
> com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade Android
> resource linking failed
> G:\flutterproject\green_doctor\marketer\marketer\build\location\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:11:9-15:56:
> AAPT: error: attribute android:foregroundServiceType not found.
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
> --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 55s The built failed likely due to AndroidX
> incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier
> to solve the incompatibility. Building plugin location... Running
> Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... √ Built build\app\outputs\repo.
> Building plugin location_web... Running Gradle task
> 'assembleAarRelease'...
>
> F:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location_web-1.0.1\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location_web\LocationWebPlugin.java:3:
> error: cannot find symbol import androidx.annotation.NonNull; ^
> symbol: class NonNull location: package androidx.annotation
> F:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location_web-1.0.1\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location_web\LocationWebPlugin.java:15:
> error: cannot find symbol public void onAttachedToEngine(@nonnull
> FlutterPluginBinding flutterPluginBinding) { } ^ symbol: class NonNull
> location: class LocationWebPlugin
> F:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location_web-1.0.1\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location_web\LocationWebPlugin.java:20:
> error: cannot find symbol public void onDetachedFromEngine(@nonnull
> FlutterPluginBinding binding) { } ^ symbol: class NonNull location:
> class LocationWebPlugin 3 errors
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task
> ':compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'. Compilation failed; see the compiler
> error output for details.
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
> --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 11s
>
> Exception: The plugin location_web could not be built due to the issue
> above.

can enybody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Which version you are using of location package?

Comment: location 3.2.4 - @ShubhamNarkhede

Answer (score 0):

try setting jetifier enabled in gradle properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```